# Fallo en expresión regular PHP

Tags: php, regex, csv

Estoy haciendo un programa que me saque datos de un CSV (eans, son como IDs, tienen que tener 13 dígitos sí o sí). El código es el siguiente:

```
$archivo=fopen("articulos_erp.csv", "r"); //abro el archivo   

while(!feof($archivo)){ //Voy leyendo el CSV

    $linea=utf8_encode(fgets($archivo)); //Leo datos con CSV y lo voy poniendo en formato UTF8
    $arrayLineas=explode(";", $linea); //Aquí tengo mi array con los datos del CSV

    if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el ean esté vacío
        if(!preg_match("/[A-Za-z]/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito los ean que tengan alguna letra
                if(!preg_match("/,/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito las comas
                   
                    $arrayLineasSinEspacios=trim($arrayLineas[0]);
                    $arrayLineasLimpio=str_replace(" ", "", $arrayLineasSinEspacios);
                    $numeroCaracteres=strlen($arrayLineasLimpio);
                    

                    switch($numeroCaracteres){

                        case 12:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="0".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="00".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break; 
                        case 9:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="0000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="00000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break; 
                        case 7:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="000000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;       
                    }

                    $arrayLineasLimpioInt = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $arrayLineasLimpio);
                   
                    if((preg_match("/^[0-9]{13}$/", $arrayLineasLimpioInt)){
                        $arrayLineasDefinitivo=$arrayLineasLimpioInt
                    })

                    echo "<pre>";
                    var_dump($arrayLineasDefinitivo);
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "</pre>";
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

El problema lo tengo aquí:

```
if((preg_match("/^[0-9]{13}$/", $arrayLineasLimpioInt)){
                        $arrayLineasDefinitivo=$arrayLineasLimpioInt
                    })
```

He estado probando en páginas de expresiones regulares, y la expresión regular está bien: sólo me matchea aquellos int que tienen 13 dígitos. Básicamente la idea es que sólo me coja aquellos eans con 13 dígitos y me los meta en el array, ya que antes de eso aunque tengo los eans bastante limpios, hay algunos con menos de 6 caracteres (si tiene menos de 7, no le meto 0 a la izquierda para completar). El problema es que no tengo ni idea de en qué estoy fallando y me sigue mostrando el array exactamente igual, con dichos caracteres. Es decir, el último if no me está limpiando nada, pero no soy capaz de dar con el fallo. A ver si alguien lo ve. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Tengo varias preguntas: ¿por qué decidiste usar `explode()` en vez de `str_getcsv()`? Y, ¿cuál es el propósito final del patrón? Según tu código `$arrayLineasDefinitivo` valdrá el último `$arrayLineasLimpioInt` que tuvo un valor válido. Lo que quiero decir es que, en caso de que no coincida el patrón, `$arrayLineasDefinitivo` mantendrá su valor anterior y no tendrá relación con el valor del registro en curso. Además, dependiendo de la versión de PHP, un número entero podría no coincidir nunca con 13 dígitos reales, porque podría tener solo 11 caracteres (`-2147483648`).

Comment: Lo del explode simplemente ví que funcionaba y que me separaba los valores por ;. No sé si str_get_csv() me podría aportar alguna cosa diferente y mejor. Entiendo que quizás el problema para que no tenga el último valor si no todos es que $arrayLimpioDefinitivo[]=$arrayLineasLimpioInt, es decir, ponerlo ahí como un array. A ver, la salida es esa, que tengan todos los registros 13 dígitos. Lo de los 11 caracteres...¿Cómo se puede controlar? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de unas líneas de CSV y la salida que esperas? Es para entender mejor cómo debería funcionar tu código. Sigo sin entender muy bien para qué usas el patrón, si es para filtrar valores incorrectos o para qué es. Con tres o cuatro líneas de CSV (que tenga una o dos que no coincidan con el patrón) y el resultado esperado es suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente era una tontería. Simplemente con poner esto ya vale:

```
$arrayLineasLimpioInt = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $arrayLineasLimpio);
                   
                    if( preg_match("/^[0-9]{13}$/", $arrayLineasLimpioInt) ) {
                        $arrayLineasDefinitivo[]=$arrayLineasLimpioInt;
                    }
```

Básicamente, necesito convertir a int porque los datos que tengo son formato string y luego necesito ponerle [] en $arrayLineasDefinitivo porque es un array. Con eso ya funciona.